# requests.get keeps hanging with Twitter Api (Python Requests library)

Tags: python, json, twitter, python-requests

My code so far:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"

r = requests.get(url, auth = ('username', 'password'))
print r.status_code
```

When I run this script in the console it keeps hanging, but when I run the equivalent urllib2 I get a good response:

```
from urllib2 import *

password_mgr = HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"
password_mgr.add_password(None, url, 'username', 'password')
h = HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = build_opener(h)
page = opener.open(url)
print page.getcode()
```

This returns `200`. Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Edit: Also, when I adjust the password in the above code, I get the appropriate `401` reponse. I think the reason for this is that there is some blocking going on?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, it only affects requests versions > 0.13.5. 
To fix, disable prefetch in the requests.get call:

```
r = requests.get(url, auth = ('username', 'password'), prefetch=False)
```

Comment: Why does this fix the problem? According to the docs, prefetch defaults to False already.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can call requests.get the way you are doing. If parameters are passed, you need to include a dictionary. Something like this ?

```
auth = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
r = requests.get("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json", params=auth)
print r.status_code
```

Read this link overall for the correct way to use requests.get
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, it's giving me 401 again. I think you have to pass the username/password combo in the "auth" parameter.